# What if logger can't log?

Tags: c#, logging, error-handling, error-logging

I've recently come across a situation when theoretically operation was completed but logger failed to write some info to the file (no write access to folder with log) and operation was reported as failed (even application broke down with exception). In my project we often use code like

```
try { /*Business logic*/}
catch (BusinessLogicEx1) {...}
catch (BusinessLogicEx2) {...}
catch (SomeKindOfException ex)
{
    LogThisException(ex);
}
```

What if log is unavailable for some reason? How do you usually treat this situation? Do you notify user somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check the log path, file availability and file access priviledges in the beginning to make sure such things don`t happen a lot.. if you still run into a locked/unavailable file

- I normally inform the user via Gui and write to a temp destination so the logging doen`t get lost
- In case no Gui is available I write a windows event entry

  ```
  System.Diagnostics.EventLog appLog =  new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();  
  appLog.Source = "This Application's Name";  
  appLog.WriteEntry("An entry to the Application event log.");
  ```
- on big projects there's a configuration management that get`s checked in the beginning and remembers errors so when the application is executed in administrator mode it can show any internal errors that occured

the best solution will be depending on your scenario

Answer (score 1):

You do a best effort graceful degradation. Try to terse log, try to log to an alternative target, using different API etc. If possible, queue the message so that it can be logged later. It really boils down to how much effort you're willing to put in, how important. And try really hard not to make a bad situation worse (cause more problems/crash app by trying *hard* to log).

The interesting question is whether to notify the user. Consider:

- is there an user to start with? If you're a service then there is nobody to see your message.
- is the *current* user the right one to notify? If this is a clerk using your kiosk then no, you should notify an admin instead.
- can the user do anything about it? "anything" may include "notify the appropiate admin". If this is the case then make sure the error message is descriptive and actionable.
- should the user (or an admin on the user site) be the one notified, or *you*, the developer (or your company)? Often time you *do* want to hear about issues, so you know what is broken in code, what usually breaks due to bad config,  what dependency is fragile (think a REST api you depend on). I will no enter into a Privacy discussion here, but you should clearly consider that angle, from legal/PR pov.
- often time you log something and display the user something else. Different audiences (end user vs. debug/admin).

I hope this proves the point that only you can answer the question, knowing that what your app does and how is used. Personally I've been in many situations where I had to clearly notify user, just as many situation where I had to silently log, and some cases where the code had to 'phone home' and report the problem to *me*.